# Postman: Is there a way to check Pre-request Scripts and Tests with ESLint?

Tags: postman, eslint

Trying to find a way to run ESLint against the code from Tests and Pre-request Scripts from Postman app.

As a workaround, I create a dummy `.js` file inside my project, copypaste my code from Postman into it and then run ESLint.

This approach works for a single request, but might be quite tedious for a whole collection.

As a matter of fact, I was thinking of writing of piece of software which would grab Tests and Pre-Request scripts from the `collection.json` file, put it in a bunch of separate .js files, run ESLint and return a file with inspection results.

Dummy `collection.json` for example:

```
                "event": [
                    {
                        "listen": "test",
                        "script": {
                            "id": "0qwe123r-t4yu-5i6o-786p-901asd2fg3h4",
                            "exec": [
                                "const planetNames = [];",
                                "",
                                "pm.response.json().results.forEach(planet => {",
                                "    console.log(`Planet name is: ${planet.name}`);",
                                "    planetNames.push(planet.name);",
                                "});",
                                "",
                                "console.log(`Planet names are: ${planetNames}`);"
                            ],
                            "type": "text/javascript"
                        }
                    }
                ],
```

However, I firstly wanted to check community thoughts.

Comment: Is this something that might help? https://github.com/matt-ball/postman-cli/issues

Comment: @DannyDainton, yeah, that could help. I'll take a look, thanks.

Comment: Have you found a good solution so far?

Comment: @igor, unfortunately, no. `Postman-cli` might help, but from my perspective, it adds too much overhead.